# Cannot resolve view in servlet

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, view, localhost, http-error

I am developing a web application in IntelliJ using Spring MVC and Spring Boot. As I am trying to access the URL of my app, it shows me that localhost page cannot be found. I suppose that the problem is about the Embedded Tomcat configuration, even though I did configure it in the application.properties file.

[LATER EDIT]

I have changed my Controlle class to:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/disciplina")
public class DisciplinaController {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(DisciplinaController.class);

    public DisciplinaController() {
        System.out.println("DisciplinaController()");
    }
    @Autowired
    private DisciplinaService disciplinaService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/discipline", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listDisciplina(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
        List<Tbldiscipline> listDisciplina = disciplinaService.getAllDiscipline();
        model.addObject("listDisciplina", listDisciplina);
        model.setViewName("Disciplina");
        return model;
    }
```

Now I am able to work with ModelandView. The following ERROR occurs:

```
2019-09-04 14:20:17.628 ERROR 4472 --- [nio-8083-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/fisediscipline] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name 'Disciplina' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'] with root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'Disciplina' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1351) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1056) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

[OLD ERROR]

This is what I get in the Console when requesting from browser "http://localhost:8083/fisediscipline/disciplina" (I cannot put the whole, because the database is pretty big):

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::  (v2.1.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT)

2019-09-04 04:50:34.204  INFO 12256 --- [           main] com.pages.licenta.LicentaApplication     : Starting LicentaApplication on DESKTOP-OIND5QF with PID 12256 (started by Eftihia in D:\4.Licenta\aplicatieLicenta Drive\aplicatieLicenta309.2\licenta)
2019-09-04 04:50:34.217  INFO 12256 --- [           main] com.pages.licenta.LicentaApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-09-04 04:50:35.837  INFO 12256 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-09-04 04:50:35.966  INFO 12256 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 107ms. Found 3 repository interfaces.
2019-09-04 04:50:37.073  INFO 12256 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dd92bfc6] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-09-04 04:50:37.497  INFO 12256 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8083 (http)
2019-09-04 04:50:37.525  INFO 12256 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-09-04 04:50:37.526  INFO 12256 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.24]
2019-09-04 04:50:37.702  INFO 12256 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/fisediscipline]          : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-09-04 04:50:37.702  INFO 12256 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3400 ms
2019-09-04 04:50:38.348  INFO 12256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-09-04 04:50:38.925  INFO 12256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-09-04 04:50:38.982  INFO 12256 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-09-04 04:50:39.083  INFO 12256 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.11.Final}
2019-09-04 04:50:39.085  INFO 12256 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-09-04 04:50:39.278  INFO 12256 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-09-04 04:50:39.461  INFO 12256 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2019-09-04 04:50:40.962  INFO 12256 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
CompetentaProfController()
CompetentaTransController()
DisciplinaController()
2019-09-04 04:50:41.664  INFO 12256 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-09-04 04:50:42.620  INFO 12256 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2019-09-04 04:50:42.730  INFO 12256 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8083 (http) with context path '/fisediscipline'
2019-09-04 04:50:42.732  INFO 12256 --- [           main] com.pages.licenta.LicentaApplication     : Started LicentaApplication in 9.192 seconds (JVM running for 11.201)
2019-09-04 04:50:43.397  INFO 12256 --- [(1)-192.168.1.5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/fisediscipline]          : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-09-04 04:50:43.398  INFO 12256 --- [(1)-192.168.1.5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-09-04 04:50:43.414  INFO 12256 --- [(1)-192.168.1.5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 16 ms
2019-09-04 04:52:53.475  INFO 12256 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: 
    select
        tbldiscipl0_.idDisciplina as idDiscip1_10_,
        tbldiscipl0_.anStudiu as anStudiu2_10_,
        tbldiscipl0_.cicluStudii as cicluStu3_10_,
        tbldiscipl0_.codDisciplina as codDisci4_10_,
        tbldiscipl0_.denumireDisciplina as denumire5_10_,
        tbldiscipl0_.idConditiiDisciplina as idCondit6_10_,
        tbldiscipl0_.idContinutDisciplina as idContin7_10_,
        tbldiscipl0_.idCoroborare as idCorobo8_10_,
        tbldiscipl0_.idDepartament as idDepart9_10_,
        tbldiscipl0_.idDomeniu as idDomen10_10_,
        tbldiscipl0_.idEvaluareDisciplina as idEvalu11_10_,
        tbldiscipl0_.idFacultate as idFacul12_10_,
        tbldiscipl0_.idObiectiveDisciplina as idObiec13_10_,
        tbldiscipl0_.idPreconditiiCompetenteDisciplina as idPreco14_10_,
        tbldiscipl0_.idSpecializare as idSpeci15_10_,
        tbldiscipl0_.idTimpActivitateDisciplina as idTimpA16_10_,
        tbldiscipl0_.idUniversitate as idUnive17_10_,
        tbldiscipl0_.prescurtareDisciplina as prescur18_10_,
        tbldiscipl0_.regimDisciplina as regimDi19_10_,
        tbldiscipl0_.semestru as semestr20_10_,
        tbldiscipl0_.tipEvaluare as tipEval21_10_ 
    from
        Tbldiscipline tbldiscipl0_
Hibernate: 
    select
        tblconditi0_.idConditiiDisciplina as idCondit1_6_0_,
        tblconditi0_.conditieDefasurareLabSem as conditie2_6_0_,
        tblconditi0_.conditieDesfasurareCurs as conditie3_6_0_ 
    from
        Tblconditiidisciplina tblconditi0_ 
    where
        tblconditi0_.idConditiiDisciplina=?
```

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pages</groupId>
    <artifactId>licenta</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>licenta</name>
    <description>Aplicatie de Gesiune</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>-->
<!--        <scope>runtime</scope>-->
<!--        <optional>true</optional>-->
<!--    </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>-->
<!--            &lt;!&ndash;<version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>&ndash;&gt;-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <!-- For iText -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.pages.licenta.LicentaApplication</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The application.properties file:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=webapp/view/pages/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

server.port=8083
server.port.http=8080
server.servlet.contextPath=/fisediscipline

server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=*.jar

spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=true   

spring.datasource.tomcat.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.tomcat.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/fisediscipline
spring.datasource.tomcat.username=root
spring.datasource.tomcat.password=psw


spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/fisediscipline
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=psw

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class DisciplinaController {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(DisciplinaController.class);

    public DisciplinaController() {
        System.out.println("DisciplinaController()");
    }
    @Autowired
    private DisciplinaService disciplinaService;



    @RequestMapping(value = "/disciplina")
    public String listDisciplina(Model model) throws IOException {
        List<Tbldiscipline> listDisciplina = disciplinaService.getAllDiscipline();
        model.addAttribute("listDisciplina", listDisciplina);
        return "Disciplina";
    }
}
```

Application configuration class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration//(exclude = {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan("com.pages")
@EntityScan("com.pages.model")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.pages.dao")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class LicentaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LicentaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I would really appreciate your help, as I am stuck here for a while and I don't know what to do. Thanks!

[UPDATE] Here is my project structure. I have also added the ViewResolver:

```
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │   └───com
│   │   │       └───pages
│   │   │           ├───config
│   │   │           ├───controller
│   │   │           │
│   │   │           ├───dao
│   │   │           │
│   │   │           ├───licenta
│   │   │           │       LicentaApplication.java
│   │   │           │       MvcConfiguration.java
│   │   │           │       ServletInitializer.java
│   │   │           │
│   │   │           ├───model
│   │   │           │
│   │   │           ├───service
│   │   │           │
│   │   │           └───utils
│   │   ├───resources
│   │   │   │   application.properties
│   │   │   │   fisediscipline.sql
│   │   │   │   hibernate.cfg.xml
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   ├───META-INF
│   │   │   │       additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   ├───static
│   │   │   └───templates
│   │   │
│   │   └───webapp
│   │       ├───META-INF
│   │       │       context.xml
│   │       │
│   │       ├───resources
│   │       │   ├───css
│   │       │   │
│   │       │   └───js
│   │       │     
│   │       │
│   │       └───WEB-INF
│   │           │   servlet-spring.xml
│   │           │
│   │           └───pages
│   │               │   CompetentaProf.jsp
│   │               │   CompetentaProfFormular.jsp
│   │               │   CompetentaTrans.jsp
│   │               │   CompetentaTransFormular.jsp
│   │               │   Disciplina.jsp
│   │               │   DisciplinaFormular.jsp
│   │               │   DisciplinaVizualizare.jsp
│   │               │   login.jsp
│   │               │
│   │               └───base
│   │                       backgr.jpg
│   │                       meta.jsp
│   │                       navigation.jsp
│   │
│   └───test
│       └───java
│           └───com
│               └───pages
│                   └───licenta
│                           LicentaApplicationTests.java
```

Now I am facing the following error:

```
2019-09-04 13:48:08.327 ERROR 11624 --- [nio-8083-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/fisediscipline/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:209) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:147) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1371) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1056) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:394) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without your project structure and bean config, I think you have misconfigured `spring.mvc.view.prefix` or did not instantiate the resolver.

Follow the tutorial [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jsp-view-example/)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have added the configureViewResolver Method and now I am getting a HTTP Status 404 not found. (See last edit)

Comment: @Maria Looks like you added a class level as well as a method level @RequestMapping(value = "/disciplina") in your controller. So, that means your url to access this endpoint would be "http://localhost:8083/fisediscipline/disciplina/disciplina". I would remove the top level annotation and then try accessing the page again. Also, it seems per your project structure, "spring.mvc.view.prefix" property should be "/WEB-INF/pages/"